# How can I pass an attribute as a param to a method which gets called on a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, lambda, proc

Confused?

I have 4 methods like this:

```
  def email_proposed_water_cost
    total = 0.00
    if self.estimate_water.count == 12
      (1..12).each_with_index do |month, index|
        total += self.estimate_water[index].proposed_cost
      end
    end
    return "$ "+number_with_precision(total, :precision => 2).to_s
  end
```

The different is the attribute of estimate_water being called - in this case proposed_cost, in other cases things like cost, need, etc.  Otherwise the methods are identical save the return statement.

I want to DRY this up by taking the enumerable section and pulling it into it's own method:

```
  def total_requested_attr(foo)
    if self.estimate_water.count == 12
      (1..12).each_with_index do |month, index|
        total += self.estimate_water[index].foo
      end
    end
    return total
  end
```

'foo' isn't evaluated as the param that I pass in (assume I adapted the earlier method to pass a string literal into this method).

I get :

```
undefined method `foo' for #<EstimateWater:0x007fa73da12570>
```

I expect 'foo' to be the thing that I pass - so if I pass 'cost' I expected the statement to execute as though I called cost on an instance of estimate_water.  It does not.

How can I make this method work by sending different attributes or some other means?

Comment: is `foo` and object or a string?

Comment: You don't need either `self.`.

Comment: just use 'send' method like self.estimate_water[index].send(params)

Comment: @CarySwoveland though correct, I dislike omitting 'self' as the code reads more ambiguously.  Including self clearly defines the next thing is an ActiveRecord relation or instance method, without it, it's possible that you are operating on a separate instance variable, which creates confusion instead of clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't really specify what foo was so I can only assume it's an attribute or method name.

You can implement this using the [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) functionality like this:

```
  def total_requested_attr(foo)
    if self.estimate_water.count == 12
      (1..12).each_with_index do |month, index|
        total += self.estimate_water[index].send(foo)
      end
    end
    return total
  end
```

Since yours is specific to some use case I can't easily showcase, I made up a sample to show you:

```
class Say
  def hello(param)
    puts "hello".send(param)
  end
end

prm = "to_i"

Say.new.hello(prm)
```

This will actually equate to `"hello".to_i` and output `0`.

Comment: .send() <== awesome.  Thanks.  Sometimes you know what you mean but don't even know the right thing to Google.  Works great!